# Safety of redirecting System folders (e.g. : program files ,users,... ) using symbolic links?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, deduplication, folder-redirection, windows-server-2012-r2

Can redirecting system folders as mentioned above using symbolic links cause problems to the system or some applications? And is there any problem if I redirect the folders to another partition on which Windows Server 2012 Data Deduplication is active?

By the way this is a single question, with the second question being a special case of the first one.

Comment: Is this for you personally or is this for an organization?  for Kiosks or Servers?  How many are connecting to this windows server?

Comment: @Back2Basics me personally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group policy supports folder redirection for %UserProfile% related directories.  The configuration options are [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781907%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).

Trying to split the windows and program files folder structure across different systems is not advised.  If you attempt to load any kernel mode drivers that also exist in the program files folder you are in for a world of hurt.  (this includes Antivirus and drivers with pretty GUI's)

If you have a lot of data in the users folder then login times are affected (15 seconds per gig generally).  If you always stay logged in then it shouldn't be a problem.  What you are describing in your second question is called "roaming profiles".  (I have my reservations in telling you this because this is overkill for a single use system)